# Using a Vector-Container of Eigen::Matrices. Why?

Tags: c++, containers, eigen

I am pretty new to C++ and trying to contribute to an open source project to improve my skills. I have nerver worked with Containers before and noticed the following typedef in the code:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> sensorMatrix;
template <template <typename, typename> class Container, typename Type>
Container<std::vector, Eigen::aligned_allocator<sensorMatrix>> sensorContainer;
```

So now I am trying to understand what they are doing here and why?

1. What is that second line doing? I dont really understand how all these templates define the container?
2. So with `Container<>` I am saving a Vector of Eigen::Matrices right?
   So now I would get a value of the matrix like this: `float val = sensorContainer[i](j,k)`, is that right?
3. Why do they do that? I just dont understand what the advantages are? Why don they use a multi dimensional matrix. So just something like this: `typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> sensorContainer;`

Comment: Can't really answer "why the author decided to do like that", you need to ask the author. But one important thing about Eigen is that you need to be careful when using it's types in std containers. Use of `Eigen::aligned_allocator` is mandatory, otherwise you end up with bunch of UB on a CPU memory level. Maybe that's why there is already a typedef for it.

Comment: Are you sure the final line is as you have, and not `Container<sensorMatrix, Eigen::aligned_allocator<sensorMatrix>> sensorContainer;`, with `std::vector` as an argument somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

> What is that second line doing?

It is defining a variable template. For each pair of "template of two type arguments" and "type" there is an object named `sensorContainer`. Note that `Type` is not used in that variable, so it probably exists to allow multiple `sensorContainer`s that use the same template parameter.

On it's own it does nothing, it needs at least one instantiation of this template.

The snippet you have isn't valid C++, as it is passing a template in the place of a type.

What that does depends on the definition of the template passed as a parameter.

> So with `Container<>` I am saving a Vector of Eigen::Matrices right? So now I would get a value of the matrix like this: `float val = sensorContainer[i](j,k)`, is that right?

We can't tell. You'd have to look at the definitions of any of the templates used, to see what they are.

> Why do they do that?

They have more than one way of combining `std::vector` (a template) with `Eigen::aligned_allocator<sensorMatrix>` (an allocator type). Notably one of the parameters of `std::vector` is an allocator for it's element type.